# Are lib files exclusively statically linked or do they need to be compiled specifically (VS2015)

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2015

I have some confusion about static and dynamic linked libraries and .lib and .dll files.

I have a project with two libraries, one I built myself and one is from an open source library.

The one I built myself is a separate project in the same solution (Visual Studio 2015, C++), and I don't need to copy over the .lib files or create a DLL for the executable to build and run

For the other open source library, I do need to copy over the .lib file and the DLL into the executable folder. However, I thought it would be possible to statically link a .lib file and not have to copy over the DLL.

Does this mean I need to compile the Open Source library differently? Like change the define *__declspec(dllexport)  to  __declspec(dllimport)* ?  Or change */mD to /mT* in compiler options?

I tried both of these, but it's still saying that it can't start without the .dll

Or can I get away with changing a setting in the executable project to link this library statically? If so, what are these settings?

EDIT: I know this is a standard question that can be looked up on google, but I haven't been able to find an exact answer for a while. Mainly, I'm confused about **what** settings need to be changed, and **which** project they need to be changed in. (The library or the executable).

I'm under assumption that static linking means the library is built into the executable, and dynamic linking means the library needs to be in a separate file, if this is incorrect, please let me know. Otherwise, I need to know how to build the library *into* the executable file.

And I can go ahead and change the build options in the open source library, and I tried this already.

Thanks,
-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows, dll files (dynamically linked libraries) need to be in the same directory as the application or on the search path. lib files (static libraries) need to be statically linked during linking (the last step of building the application). It's common in Windows so have a library come with both a dll and lib file. In this case, the lib file is an import library containing the information needed to easily link to the dll.

Place the dll file where your application will be built and statically link with the lib file. Go to 'Project->Properties->Link->Input->Additional Dependencies' and 'Project->Properties->Link->General->Additional Library Directories' to specify the static libraries you want to link.

Edit: It seems I misunderstood the question. The question is how to recompile a dynamic library as a static library. You need the source code of the library you are using along with it's Visual Studio Project file. Open the library and in `Project->Properties->General->Configuration Type' change it from Dynamic Library to Static Library.

Beware that Dynamic Library uses the Linker group of properties while the Static Library uses the Librarian group of properties. Changing between these types may cause the project to drop essential linker flags options. Since every library is different, I can't predict what you will have to do work around this. Make sure to backup the project file so you can see the original options and flags.

Comment: But this requires me to place the dll into the executable directory, which I'm trying to avoid. Is there a way to build the library into the executable?

Comment: @MiPo Sorry, I misunderstood the question. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I already tried this however, and it still requires a dll. It also builds a lib and a dll file together when I build the library. did I miss a setting somewhere? Does the Runtime Library setting in Code Generation have anything to do with this? I tried changing this too without success

Comment: If the project is set to Static Library then it will not build a dll file. Make sure that you clean up before you build the static library (perhaps the old dll file was never deleted). Are there other projects in your solution that might build the dll? Is the library you are linking itself dependent on the dll file, rather than building it? Check the build events in 'Project->Properties->Build Events' for other events that might build a dll.

Comment: No I don't see anything, and there are no references in the library to any other libraries, the only thing I can think of are the pre-processor definitions:   WIN32;_DEBUG;_WINDOWS;_USRDLL;DXL_X86_CPP_EXPORTS;    but I tried removing them and it still builds a dll

Comment: The only other thing was "Use of MFC" and I tried setting to "Use MFC in a static library" but I dont think it uses MFC for anything

Comment: Ok I think I got it, I needed to change this setting for "All Configurations". For some reason it was building in debug and the configuration was for debug but it still built the dll

Comment: That pretty much misrepresents, what LIB files are. They are import libraries, that can contain object code. They are used for compile-time linking for both DLL's as well as static libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the setting for "Static Library" for All Configurations, not just Debug, although it was building in Debug. Not sure what may have caused this. Possibly because the debug and release builds for the library were set to the same folder, it may have been overwriting the debug builds with release builds when building